# Missing required parameter for [Route: department.show] [URI: admin/department/{department}] [Missing parameter: department]

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

in laravel 8 i want route to department.show but it error.but i use department.index it work.

my route i use dynamic route.

```
Route::resource('admin/department', DepartmentController::class);
```

my index.blade i use tag a link to show data department.

```
<a href="{{ route('department.show', $value->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">แก้ไข</a>
```

my controller

```
    public function show(Department $department) {

        return view('admin.department.show', compact('department'));
    }
```

my model

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'department_name'
    ];
```

How to fix it.I'm a beginner use laravel.I appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... perhaps `$value->id` is `null` ... also you can be explicit about the parameter for the URL generation `route(..., ['department' => ....])`

Answer (score 0):

In your Blade file, change the route to include the department.

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.department.show', ['department' => $value->id]) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">แก้ไข</a>
```